# How to disable redirection from 'yes-www' to 'no-www' without affecting other kinds of redirections?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want my domain name of my WordPress blog to be *example.com* rather than *www.example.com* (together with the links in the web pages). But WordPress can automatically redirect *example.com* to *www.example.com* via [`redirect_canonical`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical). Though this function can be disabled entirely by putting `remove_filter('template_redirect' 'redirect_canonical')` in the theme's php file, I think there are many other useful redirections in the function so I want to disable the redirection from *example.com* to *www.example.com* only. Currently this cannot be done solely via the server's URL rewrite configuration because it will cause an infinite redirection loop. I also check the source code, finding following possibly relevant snippets:

```
    // www.example.com vs example.com
    $user_home = @parse_url(home_url());
    if ( !empty($user_home['host']) )
            $redirect['host'] = $user_home['host'];
    if ( empty($user_home['path']) )
            $user_home['path'] = '/';
```

and

```
    // Ignore differences in host capitalization, as this can lead to infinite redirects
    // Only redirect no-www <=> yes-www
    if ( strtolower($original['host']) == strtolower($redirect['host']) ||
            ( strtolower($original['host']) != 'www.' . strtolower($redirect['host'])
              && 'www.' . strtolower($original['host']) != strtolower($redirect['host']) ) )
            $redirect['host'] = $original['host'];
```

So do I have to change the source code or not? In either case, what should I do? Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Or more appropriately, how to do this by a custom `template_redirect` handler?

Comment: Why don't you add your own 'template_redirect' action which by using the right priority you can have run before redirect_canonical.

Comment: @MagentaCuda, thank you. I didn't know that. But how to write the custom handler in my case? Thank you.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=template_redirect

Comment: I thought about this more after seeing your question - I would remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' ) then add_action( 'template_redirect', 'your_redirect_canonical' ) then in your_redirect_canonical() call the original redirect_canonical() only when the URL is not example.com.